# SCCM 2012 R2 Console on Windows 8.1E

Tags: windows-8.1, sccm

In our lab, SCCM 2012 R2 site server & console on site server is working fine.

I installed Console (from same .iso) on Windows 8.1 Enterprise. Installation was successful. When I launch the console on Win8.1, I get this error:

> The Configuration Manager console cannot connect to the Configuration
>   Manager site database. Verify the following:
>
> - This computer has network connectivity to the SMS Provider computer.
> - Your user account has Remote Activation permission on the Configuration Manager site server and the SMS Provider computer.
> - The Configuration Manager console version is supported by the site server.
> - You are assigned to at least one role-based administration security role.
> - You have the following WMI permissions to the Root\SMS and Root\SMS\site_ namespaces: Execute Methods, Provider Write,
>     Enable Account, and Remote Enable.

Steps tried to resolve:

1. Ensured there is network connectivity. Ping is successful.
2. I am trying with Domain Admin account. It is part of SMS Admin group and has necessary permission.
3. Both Site server & console installation is done with same iso file.
4. From the console, I can access root\sms WMI namespace.
5. I have provided the 'Remote Activation' permission using Dcomcnfg.exe.
6. Disabling firewall is not helping either.
7. Reinstalled console but still same issue.
8. There is nothing useful in AdminUI.log

Please suggest what could have gone wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause. For some mysterious reason, a registry entry was missing. When the registry entries were added, SCCM Console started working. The entries are,

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ConfigMgr10\AdminUI\QueryProcessors\WQL]
"Assembly Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Configuration Manager\\AdminConsole\\bin\\AdminUI.WqlQueryEngine.dll"
"Depends On"=""
"Type"="Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlConnectionManager"
```

No idea why these were not added, even after re-install.

Source: http://sccmfaq.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/sccm-2012-r2-console-on-windows-8-1-cant-connect-to-sms-provider/